# Leaflet filtering existing featuregroup

Tags: leaflet, geojson, layers, filter

I have a leftleat map and i would like to filter the featuregroup i am displaying.

```
exp_colJSON = new L.geoJson(exp_col,{
onEachFeature: pop_col,
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {  
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
        radius: feature.properties.radius_qgis2leaf,
        fillColor: feature.properties.color_qgis2leaf,
        color: feature.properties.borderColor_qgis2leaf,
        weight: 1,
        opacity: feature.properties.transp_qgis2leaf,
        fillOpacity: feature.properties.transp_qgis2leaf    }).addTo(map).bindLabel(Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['name'])), { noHide: true });
    }
});
```

feature_group.addLayer(exp_colJSON);
exp_colJSON.addTo(map);

I also added a combobox and i would like to filter the layer's features by the value selected in the combobox. I want to campare the selected value in the combobox with the "level" property of every feature in the layer.

I have coded so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // ran when the document is fully loaded
  // retrieve the jQuery wrapped dom object identified by the selector 
  var exp_getxocolcolegiosJSON = {};
  var sel = $('#niveles');
  // assign a change listener to it
  sel.change(function(){ //inside the listener
    // retrieve the value of the object firing the event (referenced by this)
    var value = $(this).val();

    //do whatever needed here to filter the layer

    L.geoJson(exp_col, {
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
         return(feature.properties.nivelmodelo.match(/.*value.*\/)) 
     }
    }).addTo(map);

    // I know this has no sense but i don't know how to code it

  }); // close the change listener
}); // close the ready listener
```

Regards,